# How can I get the longitude and latitude of a draggable marker in Nokia Maps?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have found this code and it works very well but I'd like to know how to get that information, longitude and latitude of the draggable marker. This is the code:
[Draggable Marker](http://pastebin.com/rQTFmz7Z)

Comment: Nokia has maps? No kidding...

Comment: yeah and it's very powerfull and a nice look ;) but maybe OpenStreetView could be the best option sometimes ;)

Comment: @Dom: Nokia has bought Navteq in 2007/2008, world leader in mapping. So yes, there are into mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the coordinate of the marker while you're dragging the marker in the map control (or after), you can use the dedicated events.

Here is a updated version based on your code:

```
// Place this anywhere in the world.
var draggableMarker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker([52.500556, 13.398889], 
{  
text:  "X",  
brush: {color: '#FF0000'} ,                 
draggable: true,                     
});   

// Add the listener function to the bubbling phase of the "dragend" event
draggableMarker.addListener("dragend", function(e) {
    var coordinate = display.pixelToGeo(e.displayX, e.displayY);
    alert(coordinate);
}, false);
// Add the marker to the map.
display.objects.add(draggableMarker);
```

Here is also a complete example: http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/markers/draggable-markers.html

Comment: Thank you very much! is it posible to update in real time a textbox? I have added some jQuery code, new code:
                // Add the listener function to the bubbling phase of the "dragend" event
                draggableMarker.addListener("dragend", function (e) {
                    var coordinate = display.pixelToGeo(e.displayX, e.displayY);
                    $("#Longitude").val(coordinate.longitude.toFixed(6));

                    $("#Latitude").val(coordinate.latitude.toFixed(6));
                    //                    alert(coordinate);
                }, false);

Comment: If you want to update it in real time, then you should use another event called 'drag', see the complete list of events on Marker class right here: http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Marker.html

Comment: Hey, thank you very much!!! you're so great this is the kind of help that we need :)